# Is there a way to save posts when WordPress goes offline?

Tags: wordpress

Is there a way to save posts when WordPress goes down?

Can I use a hook that saves this post into a cookie if no internet connection?
And when I got the connection back it will "run" the offline file and upload it to the WordPress installation.

Hope you understand what I want to achieve

Answer (score 0):

For that you would have to have a client side app handling post creation.